# LSNRCTL is missing on debian (oracle 11.2.0.4g client)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, debian, listener, oracleclient

I have 2 physically separate servers. First on Debian (web_server) and the second on win2008r2 (oracle database 11.0.2.0.4). I installed the client on debian, but there is no listener (command not found). In the folder /bin no lsnrctl.

Php, apache2, oci8, libao1 olready installed
$ oracle_home
$ tns_admin installed
To oracle database connected successfully from other PC

Comment: A client does not need a listener. Everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

> I installed the client on debian, but there is no listener

**A client-only install will not install a listener.** If you want to have a listener on your machine, you need to do a database install. Probably a software only install would do the work without creating the database.

Listener won't be on the client machine, it is generally on the database server.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, my English is bad. If you use a client oracle on windows, then the listener Must be used on both the client and the server.

Comment: You need listener only on the database server. In your applicatiin server, you just need to install client. You don't need listener. Please mark it as answered, would help others.

Comment: @tandem: that's wrong. An Oracle client installation **never** needs (or has) a listener installation - regardless of the operating system.